# SurrealDB docker-compose run fails

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, surrealdb, surrealdb-rpc

I am trying to run the latest version of SurrealDB on my docker-compose setup. However, I receive the error:
‍‍

```
example-db_1   | WARNING: no logs are available with the 'local' log driver.
```

I am using docker-compose version 3.7.

Here is the bit of docker-compose.yml that calls SurrealDB.

```
version: '3.7'

...

example-db:
    <<: *example-app
    image: surrealdb/surrealdb:latest
    command: start --log trace --user ${DB_USER} --pass ${DB_PASS} file:/db/mydatabase.db
    volumes:
      - ./db:/db
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT}:8000
    networks:
      - example_network
```

How can I fix this issue?

I tried using `1.0.0beta9` image and it works but I want to use the stable `1.0.0` version. I tried pulling the image again and restarting but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your start command to match this pattern it should work.

```
start -A --auth --user root --pass pass file:/data/database
```